# How to deploy angular 17 SSR into IIS

Tags: iis, deployment, angular-ssr

Can somebody guide me on how to host angular 17 SSR, in IIS? I followed the following link however getting "This site can’t be reached" error"

https://www.thecodehubs.com/how-to-deploy-ssr-angular-universal-to-iis/

IIS is setup as follows

- Www root
  -ngssrdemo

  - borwser
  - server
  - main.js
  - web.config

Comment: This is not a site for tutorials, but you might get some basic ideas from https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/